# How to specify package/module in CVS task in ant build.xml, if my package/module name has spaces?

Tags: xml, ant, cvs, build.xml, vcs-checkout

In build.xml for my project, for checking out the codes, I am writing the following:

```
    <cvs cvsRoot=":pserver:user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:/CVSREPO_CCP_MIG" dest="${basedir}" package="My Test Project"/>
```

The following is getting displayed in the console:

```
  [cvs] cvs server: cannot find module `My' - ignored
  [cvs] cvs server: cannot find module `Test' - ignored
  [cvs] cvs server: cannot find module `Project' - ignored
  [cvs] cvs checkout: No CVSROOT specified!  Please use the `-d' option
  [cvs] cvs [checkout aborted]: or set the CVSROOT environment variable.
```

If I perform the same checkout using a project which doesn't have any spaces in module name, the code checkout is successful.

The Ant version is 1.7.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got right by modifying the CVS task tag to:

```
<cvs cvsRoot=":pserver:user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:/CVSREPO_CCP_MIG" dest="${basedir}" package="&quot;My Test Project&quot;"/>
```

Now it works!